# How can I open cytoscape file via cyrest in python?

Tags: python, api, cytoscape

I'm currently working with cytoscape and created some session file.
Then I'd like to access this file in python and get its result as an image - I'd especially like to sort it with some particular shared name when I'm requesting a result, meaning the result changes upto sorting word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library that faciliatates working with CyREST in Python. You should be able to do just about anything you can do in Cytoscape from Python. Here's the manual: https://py2cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And here are some of the steps you are looking for:

- cyclient.session.open()
- cyclient.network.list()
- cyclient.view.export()